# WASdev Liberty Openshift cartridge with local repository

Tags: ibm-cloud, websphere-liberty, openshift-cartridge

The WASdev Liberty Openshift cartridge uses the liberty buildpack to download all the necessary components (liberty runtime, jre etc.).

I wonder if it's possible to package all the components ready within the cartridge so that at the point of application creation (rhc app-create or via the web console) the buildpack hasn't got to download all this stuff?

The motivation for that is a faster provisioning of the application and the prevention of timeouts. Concerning components, the websphere liberty runtime and openJDK is all we need so far.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using your own Openshift deployment then packaging all the components within the cartridge is possible. I've updated the cartridge [README](https://github.com/WASdev/cloud.openshift.cartridge.wlp#installing-the-cartridge-into-your-own-openshift) with instructions for doing this.

For OpenShift Online, downloading the binaries for every app is the only way.